# No IPA file found when building with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios, xamarin, ipa

I'm developing my project in Visual Studio 2012 using Xamarin Monotouch. 
I choose profile Ad-Hoc, specify signing information (provision profile, identity etc) and build my project.
But I see no IPA file generated neither on my PC, nor on Mac. I tried to find it, but it was unsuccessful. It happens even in new HelloWorld project. Where can I find IPA file?
'Show IPA file' toolbar button in Visual Studio is always inactive.

When I do the same thing in Xamarin Studio on Mac it's ok, I get my IPA file.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Distribution configuration setup that I use. On either Mac or Win my IPA is created in the "\bin\iPhone\Distribution" folder. For my configuration, under "iOS IPA Options", I have the option checked for: "Build ad-hoc/enterprise package (IPA)". Are you a registered Enterprise Apple developer? You may need to research if that is required or not. I also assume you have a the Xamarin.iOS Business license too?

Comment: I'm registered Apple developer and I have Xamarin IOS Business license. And I turned on ooption Build ad-hoc/enterprise packfge (IPA)

Comment: But are you a registered apple developer for Enterprise development? That is the $299/yr program not the $99/yr. This one allows for ad-hoc distribution.

Comment: IPA file must be created in any case. By the way, the project built with Xamarin Studio on Mac creates IPA file. And it's possible to install it with iTunes. It seems to be the visual studio issue

Comment: I have the same Problem in VS there are NO files generated (without error-message) HAVE YOU SOLVED the problem in VS??

Comment: Same for me on my TFS build, no files are being generated. Local machine build with Ad-Hoc generates an ipa file in the bin output. Any ideas?